# Python implement multi threading or workerpool or multiprocessiong in beautifulsoup for multiple url scraping at once

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-advt-no-18/33742/',
        'http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-recruitment/16960/#Engg-Services2019',
        'http://www.freejobalert.com/ssc-recruitment/17522/#selection-posts']

for u in urls:
    page = requests.get(u)
    c = page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html5lib")
    row = soup.find_all("table", {"style":"width: 500px;"})[0].find_all('tr')
    dict = {}

    for i in row:
        for title in i.find_all('span', attrs={'style': 'color: #008000;'}):
            dict['Title'] = title.text

        for link in i.find_all('a', attrs={'title':'UPSC'}, href=True):
            dict['Link'] = link['href']
            print(dict)
```

Here I am scraping some specific data from multiple URLs 
at once.so it is very slow and it is taking more time means 3 times of one URL.

Is there any way to make it fast using "workerpool" or "threading" or "multiprocessing" in python.

Please help me to integrate on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your

```
def your_function(u):
    page = requests.get(u)
    c = page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html5lib")
    row = soup.find_all("table",{"style":"width: 500px;"})[0].find_all('tr')
    dict = {}
    for i in row:
        for title in i.find_all('span', attrs={
    'style':'color: #008000;'}):
            dict['Title'] = title.text
        for link in i.find_all('a',attrs={'title':'UPSC'}, href=True):
            dict['Link'] = link['href']
     return dict
```

in a function and use a pool.map (multiprocessing)

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(4) # put your number of CPU
results = pool.map(your_function,urls)
```

Basically, it's like applying the function to each of the elements of your iterable object (what you would do with map), but in a parallel fashion.

It is way easier than the traditional queue based approach to parallelism. 
[a good article about it](http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ask.py", line 93, in <module>
    results = pool.map(display('http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-advt-no-18/33742/'))
TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'

Comment: just now i have placed my code in your code. please have a look into it

Comment: map needs 2 elements: 1 a function, 2 an iterable object to which applying it (a list, an array, etc etc)

Comment: ok, done. I inserted some indentation errors while copy pasting your code. This should work. + remember, your function need a return so results could be stored somewhere